# Write 3D text in XNA

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I'd like to render three-dimensional text. In Managed DirectX, I'd use [Mesh.TextFromFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms887054.aspx) to create a 3D mesh out out of a given string with a given font, e.g.

```
var myMesh = Mesh.TextFromFont(device, myFont, "Hello World!", 0, 3DwidthOfTheText)
```

However, this method no longer exists in XNA. Is there a replacement?

Comment: http://blog.neilreed.co.uk/search/label/RenderTarget2D

Comment: @TJHeuvel: Thanks, but that's for 2D text, not 3D text.

Comment: You can stick the texture on a mesh, and make it visible in 3d space. However it wont have any depth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do extruded 3D text in XNA, the best method - providing you know what fonts you need at build-time - is probably [**Nuclex.Fonts**](https://devel.nuclex.org/framework/wiki/NuclexFonts). It imports TrueType fonts via the content pipeline into a `VectorFont` type (similar to `SpriteFont`).

[This page contains some pretty pictures and a brief tutorial](https://devel.nuclex.org/framework/wiki/VectorFonts).

(If you need to dynamically import fonts at runtime, then Nuclex might still be worth a look - it's possible it could be separated from the content pipeline.)

Answer (score -1):

One possibility is to use RenderToTexture to render your text on a mesh and just place that mesh in the world.

Comment: -1. The primary objective the OP is looking for is a mechanism that will create the 3d mesh that is the shape of the letter... like the old MDX method did.

Comment: Even if you wanted to put 2D bitmap text in your world, this is probably not the best way to go about it. The best way would be to use `SpriteBatch` with a `BasicEffect` ([details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/01/12/spritebatch-billboards-in-a-3d-world.aspx)) to draw the text directly into the world. Also this isn't even a good explanation of how to use render targets - there is no "`RenderToTexture`" type or method in XNA.